# How to build a neural network using keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to learn how to build a neural network. I'm following some online tutorials using keras. I actually don't know what is keras or tensorflow. I saw them appearing a lot. I'm trying to understand how they work by coding a neural network.

So I have a classification task of classifying reddit messages. I use bag of word representation to represent the inputs of the neural network. So here is what I did:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.utils import np_utils

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(50, activation = "relu", input_shape=(1000, )))
# Hidden - Layers
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation = "relu")
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation = "relu"))
# Output- Layer
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation = "sigmoid"))model.summary()
model.summary()
```

I got this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-15-1333ccb420e1>", line 102
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the line previous to the line with the error, you will notice that the number of left and right closing brackets are not the same.

```
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation = "relu")
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
```

should be

```
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation = "relu"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
```